# Shortcut key to open Current Wireless Network STATUS dialog window on Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, windows-10

I want to get to this **Wireless Connection Status Window** with only a keyboard shortcut as I need this often. Perhaps Windows already built this in but I don't know about it OR perhaps we can build a custom shortcut (and assign a key to it) to get this dialog box quickly and swiftly?

[image]

Comment: are you sure `netstat -e -s` does not fit your purpose better? If you do this often, you should automate this in script and get only the data you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a new text file and put the following text on it

   `rundll32.exe van.dll,RunVAN`
2. Save it as **wifi.bat** and create a shortcut of it wherever you want.
3. Right-click the shortcut, from menu select **Properties** and set keyboard shortcut to whatever you want.

Now your shortcut key will popup that Wireless network window.

Or use any other trick to map a keyboard shortcut to it ...

Comment: for me on W7 this opens a window with a list of Wireless Networks available. Not the status of current connection.

Comment: +1 for cool script in the first bullet of your answer. However it does not work on m y Windows 10: the .bat file opens up something but closes instantly, so fast I have no idea what opened and closed...

Comment: Not working on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

1. Open “Win+X” menu by hitting both of the keys collectively and choose “Network connections”.
2. Once the “Network connections” windows spreads out, locate the “Adapters” and perform a right click particularly on the one for which you are thinking to create desktop shortcut. On the right click context menu, strike the choice written as “Create shortcut”.
3. Enjoy;) & Say thank you for the providing guidance to [SUNITA](http://www.howto-connect.com/desktop-shortcut-network-connection-windows-10/)

Comment: This works for Windows 10